# Adding Corner To UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

Hi I am new in iOS development and came across with challenge that I am struggling to overcome. Basically I would like to add corner radius to UITabBarController, however I do not know how. I checked several resources in **Stackoverflow** and also **Youtube** and the solutions that people shared either were too complicated to understand or were giving errors such as **"Value of type 'UITabBarController' has no member 'layer'."**. By the way I don't use storyboard.

(Note: The comments in the code are for styling purposes. Since I could not make them work I commented them.)

Code:

```swift
import UIKit

class TabBarViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    
    var tabBarCnt: UITabBarController!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createTabBar()
        setUpBarStyle()
    }
    func createTabBar(){
        //        viewcontroller.tabBarItem.title = "Dash"
        //        viewcontroller.tabBarItem.image = UIImage.init(named: "imageName")
        //        viewcontroller.tabBarItem.selectedImage= UIImage.init(named: "imageName")
        tabBarCnt = UITabBarController()
        tabBarCnt.tabBar.barStyle = .default
//        let mapVC = MapViewController()
        let homeVC = HomeView()
//        mapVC.tabBarItem.title  = "Map"
        homeVC.title = "Home"
        tabBarCnt.viewControllers = [homeVC]
        
        self.view.addSubview(tabBarCnt.view)
        
    }
    func setUpBarStyle(){
//        would like to add corner radius
        
        
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
//
//        layer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 30, y: self.tabBarCnt.bounds.minY + 5, width: self.tabBar.bounds.width - 60, height: self.tabBar.bounds.height + 10), cornerRadius: (self.tabBar.frame.width/2)).cgPath
//        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
//        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0)
//        layer.shadowRadius = 25.0
//        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
//        layer.borderWidth = 1.0
//        layer.opacity = 1.0
//        layer.isHidden = false
//        layer.masksToBounds = false
//        layer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
//
//        self.tabBarCnt.layer.insertSublayer(layer, at: 0)
//        if let items = self.tabBarCnt.items {
//          items.forEach { item in item.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: -15, right: 0) }
//        }
//
//        self.tabBarCnt.itemWidth = 30.0
//        self.tabBarCnt.itemPositioning = .centered
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post a sample design you want to achieve? It seems you want to add some corner radius to the `UITabBar`. Can you confirm?

Comment: Hi, I Would like to have a tab bar like provided in this link. https://medium.com/@gemix95/how-to-build-round-tabbar-in-swift-b1cfb96b3358

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the existing tabBar in your `UITabBarController`.

```
func setUpBarStyle(){
    // Clipping needs to be enabled, otherwise rounded corners won't show.
    tabBarCnt.tabBar.clipsToBounds = true
    tabBarCnt.tabBar.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    // I guess you want to mask to top left and right corners. If not, change the maskedCorners to what you want.
    tabBarCnt.tabBar.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
}
```